# Sharing the dirver object initialized in base class to that of page classes

Tags: c#, selenium, oop, xunit, pageobjects

In the POM model, we ideally tend to have the driver object being initialized in base class. And in the page classed we pass this driver object. But the problem is to avoid passing this object as well and the tests should continue to work in parallel too in XUNit framework. Below is the structure

```
    public class BaseClass:IDisposable
    {
         public IWebDriver Driver{get;set;}
         public BaseClass()
         {
           if(Driver == null)
           {
             Driver = new ChromeDriver();
           }
         }
    }

    public class Page1:BaseClass
    {
       public void method1()
       {
          this.Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.google.com")
       }
    }

    public class Page2:BaseClass
    {
       public void method2()
       {
          this.Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
       }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
      [Fact]
      public void Test1()
      {
         new Page1().method1();
         new Page2().method2();
      }
    }
```

Now in the above structure if the test executes two instances of the driver object will be created because of OOPS. If we need to avoid this we can the Driver object as static and reinitialize it if the object is null. But this will again fail when we run multiple tests in parallel. Any suggession? Thing I am trying to achieve is that full encapsulation where the Test class should not have any access to Selenium objects. These objects should be only accessible in Page class or its Operation class if we have any.

Answer (score 0):

We need to ensure we create a driver singleton and its threadsafe to run parallely

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1  : TestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        new Page1().method1();
        new Page2().method2();
        Driver.Testcleanup();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        new Page1().method1();
        new Page2().method2();
        Driver.Testcleanup();
    }



    public class Page1 
    {
        public void method1()
        {
            Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }

    public class Page2 
    {
        public void method2()
        {
            Driver.Instance.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }

}
```

Driver Class will handle the initialization of the singleton and cleanup

```
public sealed class Driver
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static IWebDriver driver = null;


    public static IWebDriver Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }
    }

    public static void Testcleanup()
    {           
        driver.Quit();
        driver = null;

    }
}
```

Comment: XUnit does not have TestInitalize or ClassInitialize attributes. So this may not work. Because I will end up adding it int he constructor which will again cause problem,

Comment: This will cause a problem when you run tests in parallel, as the driver instance is Static

Comment: It shouldn't since we make it thread-static. What issue do you face? Can you provide the error stack